# Why my network TCP/UDP implementation isn't working?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, udp, sfml

I want to have a server that

- Can send and receive TCP messages.
- Can send and receive UDP messages.

multiple clients that

- Can send and receive TCP messages
- Can send and receive UDP messages.

I use basic sockets and `select` for my server and the network SFML module for the client side (http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/network-socket.php).

On the server side I create my socket, bind the TCP and UDP port to 4005.

On the client side I use the `connect(host, ip)` call for TCP, and I bind the UDP port to 4006, as my UDP port is already binded to 4005 on the server side.

**At the moment, my TCP is working fine, I can send a receive a message on both sides(client and server).**

I am trying to send a UDP packet from server to client. To do so, I am taking the sockaddr_in from the accepted client socket I want to send a message(the sockaddr_in filled by the `accept` function).

**But when I send it, my client doesn't receive it.**

I send it this way :

```
unsigned int UDPSocket::send(Message &buffer, sockaddr_in const &addr)
{
  sockaddr_in cpy;

  std::memcpy(&cpy, &addr, sizeof(sockaddr_in));
  //return ::send(_sock, buffer.getData().data(), buffer.getData().size(), 0);
  std::cout << "sending to " << buffer.getClientId() << std::endl;
  int fromsize = sizeof(sockaddr_in);
  cpy.sin_port = htons(4005 +1);
  std::cout << "sending to " << 4005 + 1 << std::endl;
  int ret = ::sendto(_sock, buffer.getMessage(), buffer.getSize(), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &cpy, fromsize);
  perror("sendto");
  std::cout << ret << std::endl;
  return ret;
}
```

ret is superior to 0 and `perror` return success, so the message should be sended.

I receive it this way :

```
bool              Network::updateQueueUDP()
{
  unsigned char   data[sizeof(Protocol::rtypePacket)];
  bool            ret = false;
  std::size_t     received;
  sf::IpAddress   sender;
  unsigned short  senderPort;

  if (_udpSocket.receive(data, sizeof(data), received, sender, senderPort) == sf::Socket::Done)
  {
    Message *msg = new Message();
    msg->setMessage(data, received, 0);
    _udpQueue.push(msg);
    std::cout << "pushing" << std::endl;
    ret = true;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

But `receive` never returns `sf::Socket::Done`

Do you have an idea why I don't receive anything in the UDP of my client ?

Comment: Where would I find the code or specification for `_udpSocket.receive`? I suspect you just don't understand precisely how it functions and it might not be the right function to use for receiving from UDP or `sf::Socket::Done` might not be the right return value to check for.

Comment: @Omnifarious On this page http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/network-socket.php

Comment: Well, hmmm... what return value are you getting?

Comment: @Omnifarious I got sf::Socket::NotReady

Comment: Oh! You put the socket into non-blocking mode. Does your program wait until `select` says it's readable before calling `updateQueueUDP`? Also, one other case is that you might have too small a buffer, but that would result in `Partial` and not `NotReady`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gived to the `sendto` function the wrong file descriptor, so it is normal it wouldn't send.

Comment: Well, given the code you showed us, we would never have figured that out. :-/